# VSCode not resolving babel absolute imports correctly for Intellisense

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, eslint, vscode-jsconfig

I am losing my mind over this. I have a very simple hello world project that I want to use Babel and ESLint in. I also want to use absolute imports, but vscode is not resolving my absolute imports correctly.

My project structure is:

```
- node_modules
- src
  - config
    - index.js
  - logger
    - index.js
  index.js
- package.json
- .babelrc
- .eslintrc
- ...
```

`src/index.js`

```js
import express from "express";
import config from "config";
import logger from "logger";

// Constants
const { port, host } = config;

// App
const app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(port, host);
logger.info(`Running on http://${host}:${port}`);
```

My code runs, eslint is not erroring and everything works fine, but vscode IntelliSense is not working properly! It's resolving to some TypeScript package not my actual file!

[image: vscode intellisense not working]

`jsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "module": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

`.babelrc`

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`.eslintrc`

```json
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": ["warn", "double"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `jsconfig.json` file:

```
"paths": {
      "*/*": ["src/*"]
    }
```

In `.babelrc` file, install `babel-plugin-module-resolver` and change to:

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "*": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X118g.png)